# How does Google index our site when you're doing a Website Optimizer experiment?

Tags: ab-testing, google-website-optimizer

I'm about to use Google's Website Optimizer to do a/b testing on the home page of my site. My question is: which of the alternative pages will google's spider index? All of them? I couldn't find any info about this on google or on GWO pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[6S Marketing wrote a good blog post](http://www.6smarketing.com/google-website-optimizer-duplicate-content-paranoia/) in response to this question.

To summarize, yes you can have duplicate content issues with an A/B test (MVT is ok), but there are steps you can take to avoid this, such as:

- [use noindex](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) in your header for page B
- [use the canonical tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) for page B to point to page A
- exclude page B in your [“robots.txt”](http://www.robotstxt.org/)
- make sure that page A is in your [sitemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps), and that the other pages are not
- do not link to page B from anywhere unless absolutely necessary (I don't know why it would be tho)

After the test is over you could setup a 301 from page B to page A as well (this is also important when a user bookmarks your page B, or linked to it)

the same goes for any other alternate pages you have like C, D, E, etc..

Comment: The noindex directive is not recommended by Google for A/B testing: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/08/website-testing-google-search.html -- I realize their blog post came after this post did, so it might be worth updating the answer.